# Can I get my text messages back from my lost iPhone?

Tags: icloud, messages, sms

I lost my iPhone so I bought a new one. I am now wanting to get my text messages back.

Can I get my text messages back? If I get my old mobile number back will my text messages come back? Does iCloud store text messages?

Comment: Do you have a backup on iCloud or iTunes?

Comment: ask the NSA for a backup :)

Answer (score 1):

If you used iCloud backup, you can restore your previous phone's backup to your new phone by resetting the new phone's Content and Settings in Settings → Reset.

iMessages are separate to SMS/MMS and will be restored when you log in with your Apple ID into iCloud. Both of these are separate from your mobile number. iCloud does not store SMS/MSS messages like iMessages, only the database in iCloud backup.

---

[This iLounge guide](http://www.ilounge.com/index.php/articles/comments/restoring-text-messages-from-an-icloud-backup/) has more information about restoring text messages from an iCloud backup.

Comment: This post does not cite any references or sources. Please help improve this post by adding citations to reliable sources. Unsourced material may be challenged and removed.